# How can I find the Mac Address or IP Address of Samsung Watch 6

Tags: untagged

It was easy to find the Watch 4 in the router->client list.  But I just cant spot the Watch 6.  It has Wifi and BLE enabled.

In `Setup -> About Watch -> Status Information`, the `Wifi Mac Address` option is grayed out.